# How to escape this code in Swift

Tags: swift, escaping

This is a very simple question.
How can I escape this code in Swift?
`find . -name "*.flv" -exec sh -c 'avconv -i "{}" -c copy "$(echo "{}" | sed s/\.[^.]*$/.mp4/g )"' \;`

I tried to use `\` to escape this, but it failed.

My Playground Screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%202016-02-29%2017.03.51.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape each and every `"` by placing a `\` in front of them. They are ending your string early.

Comment: I tried that, but it failed:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%202016-02-29%2017.22.47.png

Comment: Almost there! You don't need that last backslash before the semicolon - that's where your error is.

Comment: I want to escape the last backslash too.

Comment: Then this error:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497395/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%202016-02-29%2017.26.50.png

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I solved by myself.
This is the solution:
`let command:NSString = "find . -name \"*.flv\" -exec sh -c \'avconv -i \"{}\" -c copy \"$(echo \"{}\" | sed s/\\.[^.]*$/.mp4/g )\"' \\;"`
Thank you for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the single quote after `sh -c`